# Application freezes, but not crashes? (VISUAL BASIC)

Tags: vb.net, charts, freeze

So I have been working on a project for school and part of it has to calculate the co-ordinates for a projectile's motion, which will then be added to a chart series of points and plotted on the application. The only problem with this is that if the velocity is too high (which will increase the total time taken for the flight and the range, resulting in a larger set of co-ordinates) the application freezes - but does not crash. It doesn't show any error, which it usually would as I am using Visual Studio 2013.

I will attach the code for this process, can anyone spot why it freezes and/or how to fix it?

I am only a beginner so don't know much about programming, anything to help would be greatly appreciated.

```vb
For x As Integer = 0 To totalTime Step 0.01
    Dim xPos As Double = findXLocation(velocity, angle, x)
    Dim yPos As Double = findYLocation(velocity, angle, x, elevation, totalTime, heightOfProjectile, flightRange)

    Chart1.Series("Projection").Points.AddXY(xPos, yPos)

    Dim label As New CalloutAnnotation

    With label
        Chart1.Annotations.Add(label)
    End With
Next
```

One way I found to speed up the calculations was to decrease the step (0.01 initially) to something higher, meaning that less calculations will be done. But this would result in lots of If statements, as case statements also cause the calculation of these points to freeze. I also tried to set a variable, called 'increment' set as the step value. This could've been calculated in many different ways - I originally tried `increment = totalTime / 1000`, but again this just caused the application to completely freeze despite what velocity would be inputted.

The findYLocation and findXLocation may also be useful, and are attached below.

```vb
Public Function findYLocation(ByVal velocity As Double, ByVal angle As Double, ByVal time As Double, ByVal elevation As Double, ByVal totalTime As Double, ByVal heightOfProjectile As Double, ByVal flightRange As Double) As Double
    Dim y As Double

    y = -(0.5 * gConstant * sq(time)) + (findVerticalVelocity(velocity, angle) * time) + elevation
    ' y = Math.Round(y, 1)

    If y < 0 Then
        y = 0
    End If

    Return y
End Function

Public Function findXLocation(ByVal velocity As Double, ByVal angle As Double, ByVal time As Double) As Double
    Dim x As Double

    x = findHorizontalVelocity(velocity, angle) * time
    ' x = Math.Round(x, 1)

    If x < 0 Then
        x = 0
    End If

    Return x
End Function
```

Comment: You don't need us to spot the problem.  You just need to debug your code.  A freeze is generally going to be an infinite loop or a method that doesn't return. The cause will be obvious when you debug... so debug.  That means actually use the debugger, i.e. set a breakpoint and step through the code line by line.

Comment: @jmcilhinney can you give any pointers on where I can read about this? Sorry to be a pain but got no clue about coding

Comment: I'd recommend hitting the F1 key in Visual Studio.  Microsoft has extensive online product documentation.

Comment: If you're making your step size too small, it might not be a real freeze, it might just be that your calculations are taking a long time to finish (minutes or longer).

Comment: Do you need to plot this in realtime? Or can you calculate the points then plot later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in this line

```
For x As Integer = 0 To totalTime Step 0.01
```

x is an Integer, and when you add 0.01 to it, it will never increment. Make x a Double. Actually, you can save yourself more headaches by allowing the compiler to figure out the correct type

```
For x = 0 To totalTime Step 0.01 ' it is now Double
```

and also adding `Option Strict On` at the top of your code file will find the problem for you anyways

```
For x As Integer = 0 To totalTime Step 0.01
```

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to 'Integer'

The other answer, and the comments, suggest you should debug your code. Surely, debugging would have helped you out here. If I were you I would have let it run, put a breakpoint in the For loop, and inspected what's going on. It would have been obvious that the loop variable did not increment.

According to the other answer, you could add a Console.WriteLine to the loop. This line would work well inside the loop

```
Console.WriteLine($"Inside For loop, x:{x}, xPos:{xPos}, yPos:{yPos}")
```

which would be saying

> Inside For loop, x:0, xPos:0, yPos:10
>   Inside For loop, x:0, xPos:0, yPos:10
>   Inside For loop, x:0, xPos:0, yPos:10
>   Inside For loop, x:0, xPos:0, yPos:10
>   Inside For loop, x:0, xPos:0, yPos:10

Where you'd expect the values to be changing. They do once it's a Double

> Inside For loop, x:0, xPos:0, yPos:10
>   Inside For loop, x:0.01, xPos:0.0707106781186548, yPos:11.6202267316012
>   Inside For loop, x:0.02, xPos:0.14142135623731, yPos:12.3327679741871
>   Inside For loop, x:0.03, xPos:0.212132034355964, yPos:12.8959725661313
>   Inside For loop, x:0.04, xPos:0.282842712474619, yPos:13.3818748194396

I still don't think this is complete.

There is no reason to do run your entire loop on the UI. So separate your processing and the UI. There are many ways to achieve this. One is using [Async/Await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/), and I see it as the simplest way. Understand that when you are operating off the UI, you will need to Invoke calls back to the UI to do any updates there.

The biggest performance hit you create is adding an annotation to the chart for every since 0.01 increment in time. Is this really necessary? Without adding the annotations, the plotting is very quick. With annotations it quickly slows to a crawl.

Do you need to keep processing once y has reached zero? I added some logic to exit the loop once it happens.

Note the Await will send the code off the UI so your UI will be interactive while running. Here is some code which demonstrates that. Note, the annotations are added every 0.1 seconds instead of 0.01. They are effectively decimated. You can fool around with it to make it work how you need it to.

```
Private gConstant As Double = 9.8
Private totalTime As Double
Private velocity As Double
Private angle As Double
Private elevation As Double
Private heightOfProjectile As Double
Private flightRange As Double

Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    totalTime = 100
    velocity = 100
    angle = Math.PI / 4
    elevation = 100
    heightOfProjectile = 10
    flightRange = 10
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum = 0
    Chart1.Series("Projection").ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine
    Await Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf getPoints)
End Sub

Private Sub getPoints()
    For x As Double = 0 To totalTime Step 0.01
        Dim xPos As Double = findXLocation(velocity, angle, x)
        Dim yPos As Double = findYLocation(velocity, angle, x, elevation, totalTime, heightOfProjectile, flightRange)
        Dim l = x
        Chart1.Invoke(
            Sub()
                Chart1.Series("Projection").Points.AddXY(xPos, yPos)
                If CInt(100 * l) Mod 10 = 0 Then Chart1.Annotations.Add(New CalloutAnnotation())
            End Sub)
        Console.WriteLine($"Inside For loop, x:{x}, xPos:{xPos}, yPos:{yPos}")
        If yPos = 0 Then Exit For
    Next
End Sub

Public Function findYLocation(ByVal velocity As Double, ByVal angle As Double, ByVal time As Double, ByVal elevation As Double, ByVal totalTime As Double, ByVal heightOfProjectile As Double, ByVal flightRange As Double) As Double
    Return Math.Max(0, -0.5 * gConstant * sq(time) + findVerticalVelocity(velocity, angle) * time + elevation)
End Function

Private Function sq(value As Double) As Double
    Return value ^ 2
End Function

Public Function findXLocation(ByVal velocity As Double, ByVal angle As Double, ByVal time As Double) As Double
    Return Math.Max(0, findHorizontalVelocity(velocity, angle) * time)
End Function

Private Function findVerticalVelocity(velocity As Double, angle As Double) As Double
    Return Math.Sin(angle) * velocity
End Function

Private Function findHorizontalVelocity(velocity As Double, angle As Double) As Double
    Return Math.Cos(angle) * velocity
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: I'd be very skeptical of using a `For` loop on a `Double`.  Possible issues include never terminating, or running one more step than you would expect, due to 0.01 not having an exact representation in binary floating point (with the outcome depending on details of exactly how VB implements a `For` loop).  A better approach would be to continue to use an integer increment, and then set the FP value based on your fractional advancement through the range.

Comment: @Craig I found a page which addresses what you're talking about: http://csharphelper.com/blog/2018/05/control-a-loop-that-uses-floating-point-values-in-c/

Answer (score 1):

You can try to pause the program and check what operation is causing your program to freeze (button on the left, next to the stop button in Visual Studio). 
[image: Pause button on the left]

Also you could try to add some logging to your code to see where the problem actually lies.

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Logging")
```

Or even time your calculations (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8 for more info)